# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key specialityId'.'

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net-mvc, razor

Model class-

```
public int specialityId { get; set; }
public string specialityName{ get;set; }
```

Service class-

```
public DbSet<speciality> specialities { get; set; }
```

Controller class-

```
AddService db = new AddService();
IEnumerable<speciality> specialityList = db.specialities.ToList();
ViewBag.specialId = new SelectList(specialityList,"specialityId","specialityName");
```

View page-

```
<div>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.specialityId, ViewBag.specialId as SelectList, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:300px;" })</div>
```

I have created a form in a Razor view page. It has other fields also. When I am trying to submit the data of the form I am getting the run time error for the speciality field as follows:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key specialityId'.'

Comment: Make sure the `specialityList` is not empty collection.

Comment: I am retrieving the data of specialitylist from mysql database specialities table,and in the table i have hardcoded the values in speciality table.Still it is throwing this exception.

Comment: is your  collection has specialtyId in it??

Comment: The specialityId is only present in the model class.Can you please suggest how to add specialityId in thecollection?I mean how to implement that.?Thanks a lot in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: The data that I am getting from the specilaities table is being converted to list and the specilaityList is getting initialized there.That's how I have understood.Do I need to initialize the specialitylist anywhere else?

Comment: what your db.specialities will return ..can you post keep break point and see what it contains

Comment: That problem has been solved.There were certain issues in the model binding which has been resolved. Thanks everyone for your helpful responses.

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS

Controller:

```
ViewBag.specialId = db.specialities;
```

**If your Column is Required Make sure your ViewBag return data and select one option. You can invalided using javascript**

View:

```
<div>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.specialityId,new SelectList(ViewBag.specialId,"specialityId","specialityName"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:300px;" })
</div>
```

Comment: I have not made the column of specialityId as required.And how to make sure whether the ViewBag is returning data or not?I have passed the model class to the post method.

Comment: Is ViewBag receive data and pass it to view?

Comment: That problem has been solved.There were certain issues in the model binding which has been resolved. Thanks everyone for your helpful responses.